# Парсинг большого файла (книги)

Tags: c++

Подскажите. Парсинг работает, но очень, очень долго. Посоветуйте как можно оптимизировать данный код:

```
        void Helper::ParsingFile(std::string path)
        {
        std::ifstream file(path);            
        std::string str;
            std::string item;
            listWords.clear();
            while (!file.eof())
            {
                getline(file, str);
                if (!str.empty())
                {  //если не буква кирилица или латин. то заменяю на ' '; 
                    CheckReplace(str); //вот тут проверяю каждый символ
                }
                string temp;
                for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
                {

                    if (str[i] != ' ')
                    {
                        temp += str[i];
                    }
                    else if (str[i] == ' ' && !temp.empty())
                    {   
                        ToLower(temp); // не работает с кирилицей
                        listWords.push_back(temp);
                        temp = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Какого размера Ваш файл?

Comment: `string temp` поменяйте на буфер `char[]` фиксированного размера, например на `str.size()`, в конце пишите `'\0'`. Если нужна скорость, пишите на Си.

Comment: += для строк работает не очень хорошо. Стоит запоминать индекс начала, индекс конца слова и делать substr. Хотя мне кажется, что узкое место работа с дискам. Без профайлера это точно не узнать.

Comment: При файлах больше 100 Мб рекомендую блочный метод чтения.